# Changing the position of qlabel dynamically

Tags: c++, qt

I am a newbie in QT programming and I have a question. I have a qslider and qlabel and a video playing. While video is playing, tick of qslider is moving forward as you can guess. What I want to do is to put a qlabel just under the tick of qslider and moving it with the tick as the text of qlabel is updating...

Comment: you can use setGeometry as well to change its position on the dialog...

Answer (score 2):

You can't 'move' QLavel all over the widget due to the [Qt layout system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/layout.html): the widget exists inside a layout. 
So if you want to 'move' your label just only vertically of horizontally there are few ways to solve your problem.

The easiest one is to use the `QLabel::setIndent` function (it will 'move' text inside the `QLabel`):

> If a label displays text, the indent applies to the left edge if alignment() is Qt::AlignLeft, to the right edge if alignment() is Qt::AlignRight, to the top edge if alignment() is Qt::AlignTop, and to the bottom edge if alignment() is Qt::AlignBottom.

Also you can try this way (it will 'move' `QLabel` itself):

1. Create box layout (`QHBoxLayout` or `QVBoxLayout`).
2. Add a stretch (calling `QBoxLayout::addStretch`).
3. Add QLabel (calling `QLayout::addWidget`).
4. Add a stretch once again.
5. Then you can change the stretching factors for 'move' imitation.

The initial stretch factor's value will define the initial position of the label.

The code example to simulate QLabel moving left to right:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
  {
    layout_ = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    layout_->addStretch();
    layout_->addWidget(new QLabel("Moving text", this));
    layout_->addStretch(100);

    connect(&timer_, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(moveLabel()));
    timer_.start(1000);
  }

public slots:
  void moveLabel()
  {
    layout_->setStretch(0, layout_->stretch(0) + 1);
    layout_->setStretch(1, layout_->stretch(1) - 1);

    if(layout_->stretch(0) == 100)
      timer_.stop();
  }

private:
  QBoxLayout* layout_;
  QTimer timer_;
};
```

And another variant for your situation is to inherit `QSlider` and then reimplement protected function `QWidget::paintEvent` in order to paint some label over the slider.

Answer (score 0):

First you can try QLabel.setIndent(self, int), call it whenever the tick changes. If this works for you it's the easiest possibility, if not please repost.

Comment: Thank you, but what is self in QLabel.setIndent(self, int)?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of setIndent, in this and other methods they use self as first parameter. My interpretation is that this is an implicit parameter that is given by the receiver of the message like in Python. So i think it works if you just call yourQLabel.setIndent(int). "yourQLabel" is the first (implicit) parameter.